# Black border around chat text input

Tags: support, design, chat

I suddenly notice a black border around the chat text box:

[image: black border around chat text box]

Why is that, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not Stack Exchange's fault, it's your fault.

You have enabled (maybe by mistake) an experimental flag in Chrome's settings called "Web Platform Controls updated UI":

[image: chrome flag enabled]

Copy and paste `chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh` into your address bar to quickly hop to this setting.

After disabling it and re-launching the browser, the  border should be back to normal again.

Happy chatting!

Edit: looks like that as of Chrome 83, the default is Enabled so don't set to default.

Comment: Those are some excellent [circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/622284), by the way.

Comment: @Spevacus thanks! I'm really proud of my circles. :D